# I can't figure out how to use a loop and a counter

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a program that can search for letters the user wants to search. The user will write something down in the TextBox and when he/she presses search an InputBox will appear asking him to write a letter on the InputBox.The program will then tell you have many time the letter appears in the TextBox. This is what I have so far:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub BtnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click
        TxtboxInput.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnQuit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnQuit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
        Dim intStartIndex As Integer
        Dim intFoundIndex As Integer
        Dim counter = 0
        Dim hitcounter = 0
        Dim blnFlag = True
        Try

            InputBox(" Enter Letters", "Input Needed")
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How do you want to use the loop and counter?

Comment: You want to search from where and inputbox is for what? Please write your question clearly

Comment: Do until and counter = +1

Comment: Letter or Letters, are you limiting it to a single character?

Comment: Yes, only one character

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but if you are limiting it to a single character then something like this should work.

```
Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
    Dim counter = 0
    Try
        Dim search As String = InputBox(" Enter Letters", "Input Needed")
        For Each c As Char In TxtboxInput.Text
            If c.ToString = search Then
                counter += 1
            End If
        Next
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The way that I am iterating the example is case sensitive. If you want case insensitivity then you need to convert your values to either upper or lower case. i.e.  `c.ToString.ToLower = search.ToLower`

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been having trouble in my VB class and this will definitely help.

Comment: I am getting an error message saying that counter is not declared.

Comment: This is just a code snippit you need to use the declaration of counter that you posted in your example. I will modify answer to show complete code